# how to define 3 way relationship in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

Table schema

```
Items
    id
    name
    :belongsToMany(Addon) // relations

Addons
    id
    name
    :belongsToMany(Item) // relations

addon_item
    addon_id
    item_id

orders
    id
    :hasMany(Item) // relations

item_order
    item_id
    order_id

    name    // extra pivot attr
    price   // extra pivot attr
    qty     // extra pivot attr
```

Now how do I define relation between order->items & addons
so that I can get it like `Orders::all()->items()->orderedAddons` (here I want to get only **ordered addons not all addons that the item has**)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with()` to filter `addons` and use `has()` to add condition that `addons` must have `orders` relationship.

```
Item::with(['addons' => function ($query) {
    $query->has('items.orders');
}])
->get();
```

If you want all orders with items in the same condition, you can add another `with()`

```
Order::with(['items' => function ($query) {
    $query->with(['addons' => function ($query) {
        $query->has('items.orders');
    }])
}])
->get();
```

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve order details like: `Orders::with('items')...`. How to do it in this way.

Comment: @APu yes, you can do that.